# Getting Trusteedata error when send the item back to author

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am trying to send the item back to auther in workflow using coresrvice, the below is my code, am getting compile error on casting betweento usrdata to linktotrusteedata.

```
        WorkItemData workitem = (WorkItemData)csClient.Read(workitemid, readoption);
        ProcessInstanceData processInstance = (ProcessInstanceData)csClient.Read(workitem.Process.IdRef, readoption);
        IEnumerable<ActivityData> ieActivities = processInstance.Activities;

        if (ieActivities != null)
        {
            ActivityInstanceData targetactivity = (ActivityInstanceData)csClient.Read(processInstance.Activities[0].Id, readoption);
            UserData lastperformer = (UserData)csClient.Read(processInstance.Activities[0].Owner.IdRef, readoption);                
            ActivityFinishData finishData = new ActivityFinishData(); 
            finishData.Message = "Finished automatically";
            finishData.NextAssignee = lastperformer;
            csClient.FinishActivity(targetactivity.Id, finishData, readoption); 
            csClient.Close(); 

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `LinkToUserData` object already, so can't you assign `processInstance.Activities[0].Owner` to `finishData.NextAssignee`, or use the `Owner` property (`LinkToUserData`) to construct a new data object?

Or is there a specific reason you read the `UserData`?

Comment: TrusteeData nextassignee = new TrusteeData { Id = processInstance.Activities[0].Owner.IdRef }; finishData.NextAssignee = nextassignee; am trying like this, but still getting convert type error

Comment: You should not use TrusteeData, UserData or GroupData (that are derived from TrusteeData), but create a LinkToTrusteeData object.

Since the Owner property is a LinkToUserData object you can reuse the object, or use it to construct a new data object.

Comment: LinkToTrusteeData lnktr = new LinkToTrusteeData { IdRef = processInstance.Activities[0].Owner.IdRef, Title = processInstance.Activities[0].Owner.Title };
                finishData.NextAssignee = lnktr; Have tried like this also, but the activity is not finished and not moved back to author

Comment: And when i try to log the lnktr details am getting "Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.LinkToTrusteeData" but i was expecting the user tcm id or title

Comment: Can you paste all your code here, or clarify your original answer with what you have?

Comment: Did you try the Link<Of T> example as proposed by Peter Kjaer?

Comment: if (ieActivities != null)
            {
                ActivityInstanceData targetactivity = (ActivityInstanceData)csClient.Read(processInstance.Activities[0].Id, readoption);
                ActivityFinishData finishData = new ActivityFinishData(); 
                finishData.NextAssignee = new LinkToTrusteeData { IdRef = processInstance.Activities[0].Owner.IdRef , Title = processInstance.Activities[0].Owner.Title};               
  csClient.FinishActivity(targetactivity.Id, finishData, readoption); 
                csClient.Close(); 
                
            }

Answer (score 1):

The NextAssignee property is of type `Link<TrusteeData>` but you are setting it to a `UserData` object. You probably need to create a new Link and fill in the ID and Title of it.

This should work (untested):

```cs
[...]
Link<UserData> lastperformer = processInstance.Activities[0].Owner;                
ActivityFinishData finishData = new ActivityFinishData(); 
finishData.Message = "Finished automatically";
finishData.NextAssignee = new Link<TrusteeData> { Id = lastperformer.Id, Title = lastperformer.Title };
csClient.FinishActivity(targetactivity.Id, finishData, readoption); 
[...]
```

It's also possible that it can work if you just set NextAssignee to the lastperformer variable, since UserData inherits from TrusteeData - but I'm not certain about that. Give it a try?

Comment: TrusteeData nextassignee = new TrusteeData { Id = processInstance.Activities[0].Owner.IdRef };

                finishData.NextAssignee = nextassignee; am trying like this, but still getting convert type error

Comment: That's not what I wrote, so I'm not surprised that you are still getting the convert error. It needs to be a Link object.